# Static Content missing less files

Tags: magento2, less

I have set the client side compilation mode on within admin and have recieved lots of missing files errors. Error:

```
FileError: 'http://magento2.com/static/version1493890573/_cache/merged/source/_theme.less' wasn't found (404)
```

I have tried clearing static files and redploying them however the less files are not generated and only merged css files seem to be present on there.

I am wondering what to do here and if there is a way to disable client side compilation from shell or in database but would also like to fix the static deployment so the files are deployed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it from the database.

Try running the following in your database.

```
update core_config_data set value='server_side_compilation' where path = 'dev/front_end_development_workflow/type';
```

Comment: Thanks yeah just found this and am back up again. Still a bit worried about why the files are not being found in the first place now.

Comment: Does your site runs in production mode?

Comment: Yeah seems fine in production.